# picture is not full width on load up, only after re-sizing window

Tags: html, background, scale

I just can't figure out why my background and div is not on its place on load up. Only after re-sizing the window. How can I load it differently? What could be the problem?

http://wear.gfg.me.uk/

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the circular graphic that appears when you are not in full screen? I believe that behavior is specified at the link below and am not sure what you want to accomplish.

What do you mean when you say it's "not on its place"?

http://wear.gfg.me.uk/js/screen.js

Comment: try to re-size the window, it will jump to a different place, only when you re-sizing

Answer (score 0):

You have a function call in screen.js to make the background image fullsize. It runs on resize and focus, but not when the dom is loaded. You either need to move the script to the bottom (guaranteeing that all elements including the `.background` element will be loaded when you first call `backgroundResize()` OR you can leave it at the top and call it when the dom is ready. You're already using jQuery, so you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    backgroundResize();
});
```

Comment: thank you, I've tried to include the script, but its still the same

Comment: Hm -- it is fixed for me. The photo goes from edge to edge upon first load.